# Wordpress Redirect to 404

Tags: wordpress, redirect

If I try to use link like `http://site_name/post_name/546/`, I would be redirected to `http://site_name/post_name/`. Is there any way to make redirect to `404` page in this case (only if last part of url contains numbers)?

Comment: Is 546 an ID of the post in this case?

Comment: No, just random numbers for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
RedirectMatch 301 /404 http://site_name/post_name/546/